# Custom theme creation for Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, themes

I would like to create a custom theme for Outlook 2007 and use it as default.
Running Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new email message (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and change formatting as you want. Then go to "Options" tab and click on "Themes" button. Select "Save current theme..." to save your theme in `.thmx` format.